# Is there C# Compiler define for 'Optimized code' like there is DEBUG or TRACE?

Tags: c#

I have piece of code that I can optimize to gain boost in 'Debug' without 'Optimize code' checked.
But when optimized by C# (csc) compiler I can gain a little more speed. So I would like to detect if 'Optimize code' is checked in project configuration in code, and yield best optimization for selected option.

So, is there C# Compiler define for 'Optimized code' like there is DEBUG or TRACE?

Comment: You can add your own defines: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/define-compiler-option

Comment: Why are you even trying to increase the performance of code running in Debug? You don't (shouldn't) be shipping debug binaries, so performance shouldn't matter.

Comment: Processing 10 GB dicom data would take infinity in debug. And as I am still in development phase I would like to save my own time while performing tests, although test data will grow as I implement different Dicom TransferSyntaxes need to add more and more tests. I am little exaggerating have atm only 630MB... Parsing only JPEG-LOSSLESS and RAW data and it takes only 1.5 seconds but it will grow as time (code) goes on.

Comment: Then your actual problem is that your dataset is too large for debugging with. Would it not be possible to limit the input data for your debugging session to only what's necessary, then run the full dataset through all your tests overnight, for example?

Comment: Well I could limit dataset, if I publish code to github or similar. But at the moment I am writing optimized code for bits reading (actually done this already) and writing huffman encoded pixels and need large data sample to validate functions properly, and to actually see any difference in speed (what makes it tick over the top). And discovered that some of my optimizations while they have optimized code in debug version, they fail vs Compiler Optimized version, not by much but enough.
So I want to compile best version per selected project options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not sure if there is, or if there isn't compiler define for 'Optimize Code' option.
But Kit's answer gave me an idea to change project file for MSBuild to recognize if 'Optimize Code' option is enabled, and to inject compiler define OPTIMIZED during the build.

And the solution was rather very simple, edited project file and added PropertyGroup below all property groups:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <DefineConstants Condition="'$(Optimize)' == 'true'">$(DefineConstants),OPTIMIZED</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

and tested the value of DefineConstants by adding at the bottom of the project file the following code:

```
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Message Importance="high" Condition="'$(Optimize)' == 'true'" Text="Project is Optimized, compiler defines : '$(DefineConstants)'" />
    <Message Importance="high" Condition="'$(Optimize)' == 'false'" Text="Project is Not Optimized, compiler defines : '$(DefineConstants)'" />
  </Target>
```

This yielded perfect result as define was recognized in code

```
  Project is Optimized, compiler defines : 'DEBUG,TRACE,OPTIMIZED'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not. When you check **Optimize code** Visual Studio will update your `.csproj` file with

```
<Optimize>true</Optimize>
```

I think your best bet would be to define your own conditional compilation symbol and check for that.